# who had used clipboard in vue? It doesn't work on the first click, was it caused by dynamic dom?

Tags: vue.js, clipboard

```
Vue.prototype.$copyText = function (text, select,container) {
    var btn = document.querySelector(select);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var clipboard = new Clipboard(btn, {
            text: function () {
                return text;
            },
            action: function () {
                return 'copy'
            },
            container: typeof container === 'object' ? container : 
                document.body
            });
            clipboard.on('success', function (e) {
                clipboard.destroy();
                resolve(e);
            });
            clipboard.on('error', function (e) {
                clipboard.destroy();
                reject(e);
            });
        });
    }
```

> It doesn't work on the first click, was it caused by dynamic dom??when first click the dom is cann't get,is undefined

Comment: Show me the code that invokes this method

Comment: let link = "https://www.codepku.com/activity?slug=" + data;
let _dom = "#level4 button[action='copy']";
this.$copyText(link, _dom).then(() => {
    this.$swal('well done', 'copy success', 'success');
}, (e) => {
    this.$swal('error', 'copy fail', 'error');
});

Comment: These code doesn't tell the story.It is certain that the DOM element does not exist when the code is executed.